# switch_to_blog() for parent theme

Tags: parent-theme, switch-to-blog

all.  Just trying out switch_to_blog() as a way to have a child site get some news items from the parent site.  Problem is, the parent site--first tables in database--doesn't have a number, i.e., tables are like www_posts--there's no number to put in the parentheses, 0 doesn't work, empty doesn't work.

How can I reference this original install?  Also, is it no longer cool to use switch_to_blog()?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`switch_to_blog(1);` to switch to the root (primary) blog and pull post info.

`restore_current_blog();` to switch back.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use site transients store the news items.  That way it would be accessible from all network sites and you wouldn't have to call switch_to_blog to access them as I believe it is quite server intensive.

[Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API)

And the specific function you would want to use for network access would be:

```
set_site_transient('recentnews', 'yournewsoutputhere', expiretime);

<?php echo get_site_transient('recentnews'); ?>
```